# Binding element 'posts' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, graphql, tailwind-css

I have this code I'm writing that involves graphql, react and typescript. Halfway in and I'm getting the error message **Binding element 'posts' implicitly has an 'any' type.**
I have no idea what this means and need help.
Below is the code where the error is coming from, thanks

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import {PostCard, Categories, PostWidget} from '../components'
import {getPosts} from '../services'

export default function Home({posts}) {
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-10 mb-8">
      <Head>
        <title>FTS Blog</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-12">
        <div  className='lg:col-span-8 col-span-1'>
          {posts.map((post) => <PostCard post={post} key={post.title}/>)}
        </div>
      
        <div className="lg:col-span-4 col-span-1">
          <div className="classname lg:sticky relative top-8">
            <PostWidget />
            <Categories />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = (await getPosts()) || []

  return {
    props:{posts}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use the interface in typescript

this syntax will solve your problem:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';

interface HomeProps{
    posts:any[]
}

const Home: NextPage<HomeProps> = ({ posts }) => (
<div className="container mx-auto px-10 mb-8">
    <Head>
        <title>FTS Blog</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>

    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-12">
        <div  className='lg:col-span-8 col-span-1'>
            {posts.map((post) => <PostCard post={post} key={post.title}/>)}
        </div>

        <div className="lg:col-span-4 col-span-1">
            <div className="classname lg:sticky relative top-8">
                <PostWidget />
                <Categories />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
  );

export default Home;
```

Comment: It worked and displayed without error on the browser. However, I still have the error message "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." displaying in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from Typescript letting you know that your prop `posts` does not have a type defined, so it is being assumed to be the type, `any`.

You can make the error go away by *explicitly* giving `posts` the type of `any`, but `posts` is clearly supposed to be an array based on this line on code you have: `posts.map((post) => ...`. So you probably want to give `posts` the type of an `any array` like this:

```
export default function Home({posts}: {posts: any[]}) {
```

Nextjs has some additional info about [how to use getStaticProps with Typescript](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#static-generation-and-server-side-rendering)